# How to assign a different Joomla template style to subpages?

Tags: templates, joomla3.0

How to make the sub articles have different template style and not inherit the one assigned to their parent category?

Let's say that I have news category which uses the default template style. How can I assign a different template style the single articles of that category.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Template Manager by RegularLabs will work for this, it allows to you assign different templates based an a number of different rules

https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/advancedtemplatemanager

And its free!

Comment: I know about it but unfortunately, it will not work with templates based on Gantry Framework. That's why I'm looking for other ways.

Comment: is making menu items for each article not an option?

Comment: I have 100s of article :(